# python: Find camera shift angle using a reference image and current image from the camera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision

I have a reference image captured from a cc-camera and need to capture current image from the cc-camera to check if the camera is shifted or not at regular intervals. If shifted, the shift angle must also be needed. How can I achieve this using python?   Is the **cv2.phaseCorrelate()** function be helpful for this. Please give me some suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of hanning window will be more accurate for getting the phase values. Use phase correlate function with the window will give you a right phase shift.